# Enable sale price for logged users and regular price for unlogged users in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

In Woocommerce I have a variable products with many variations and every variation has its own REGULAR price and SALE price.

I would like when user:

- is logged in, the sale price will be the active price
- is not logged in, the regular price will be the active price.

I have added this hooked function in my child theme function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'my_variation', 10, 3);
function my_variation( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());
     $variation_id = $variation->get_id();
     $variable_product1= new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
     if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $regular_price = $variable_product1 ->regular_price;
             $data['price_html'] = woocommerce_price($regular_price);
             return $data;
             }  else { 
              $sale_price = $variable_product1 ->sale_price;
         $data['price_html'] = woocommerce_price($sale_price);
         return $data;
        
        }
    
}
```

The displayed price works… But when I add to cart any product it remains only with the sale price in in cart…

Answer (score 2):

The code below will:

- enable regular price for non logged users only everywhere
- enable sale price for logged users only everywhere
- hide the sale flash badge
- remove the sale price range

The code:

```
// Variable and simple product displayed prices (removing sale price range)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_get_price_html', 20, 2 );
function custom_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    if( $product->is_type('variable') )
    {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ){
            $price_min  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_sale_price('min') ) );
            $price_max  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_sale_price('max') ) );
        } else {
            $price_min  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_regular_price('min') ) );
            $price_max  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_regular_price('max') ) );
        }

        if( $price_min != $price_max ){
            if( $price_min == 0 && $price_max > 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_max );
            elseif( $price_min > 0 && $price_max == 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_min );
            else
                $price = wc_format_price_range( $price_min, $price_max );
        } else {
            if( $price_min > 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_min);
        }
    }
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple') )
    {
        if( is_user_logged_in() )
            $active_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );
        else
            $active_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );

        if( $active_price > 0 )
            $price = wc_price($active_price);
    }
    return $price;
}

// Product Variation displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 3);
function custom_variation_price( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    $reg_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => $variation->get_regular_price() ) );
    $sale_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => $variation->get_sale_price() ) );

    if( is_user_logged_in() )
        $data['price_html'] = wc_price( $sale_price );
    else
        $data['price_html'] = wc_price( $reg_price );

    return $data;
}

// Set the correct prices in cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_item_cart_prices', 20, 1 );
function set_item_cart_prices( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price() );
        }
    }
}

// Remove sale badge
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash', 10 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Update**: [Enable back price suffix to a function that display customized product prices in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023673/enable-back-price-suffix-to-a-function-that-display-customized-product-prices-in/56024236#56024236)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me! Thanks a lot for the code!
This code helps my customer to add prices for their "members" very easily.

They just complete regular and sale price.
Wholesale plugins are much more complex and are not needed in this case.
*I mean in the case that only logged in users should see the "sale price".