# Enable back price suffix to a function that display customized product prices in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I am using *"[Enable sale price for logged users and regular price for unlogged users in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706432/enable-sale-price-for-logged-users-and-regular-price-for-unlogged-users-in-wooco/49727995#49727995)"* first function code, that hides sales price. That way I can use sales price and regular price for logged in vs none logged in users and it Works like a charm.

The Problem I have is that it also kills the woocommerce_price_suffix field from the settings and I want to include it in my function, but don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will add back the price suffix:

```
//Variable and simple product displayed prices (removing sale price range)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_get_price_html', 20, 2 );
function custom_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type('variable') )
    {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ){
            $price_min  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_sale_price('min') ) );
            $price_max  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_sale_price('max') ) );
        } else {
            $price_min  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_regular_price('min') ) );
            $price_max  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_regular_price('max') ) );
        }

        if( $price_min != $price_max ){
            if( $price_min == 0 && $price_max > 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_max );
            elseif( $price_min > 0 && $price_max == 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_min );
            else
                $price = wc_format_price_range( $price_min, $price_max );
        } else {
            if( $price_min > 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_min);
        }
        $price .= $product->get_price_suffix()
    }
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple') )
    {
        if( is_user_logged_in() )
            $active_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );
        else
            $active_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );

        if( $active_price > 0 )
            $price = wc_price($active_price) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

Comment: You are such a helpful awesome person :) Not the first time you help me with my problems. Thank you so very much. Worked like a charm!