# Woocommerce - Display both regular and sale product price for logged in customers

Tags: php, woocommerce

For an upcoming sale, we have our existing registered customers will have a 'pre-order'. So they can avail of the sale prices they must be logged in. These prices need to be displayed anywhere where a product is displayed.

For logged-in customers I need to display **both** the regular price (slashed out) and the sale price otherwise guess. Plus I need to do this for both variable and simple products.

At the moment I have this code ([Enable sale price for logged users and regular price for unlogged users in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706432/enable-sale-price-for-logged-users-and-regular-price-for-unlogged-users-in-wooco) )

```
// Variable and simple product displayed prices (removing sale price range)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_get_price_html', 20, 2 );
function custom_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    if( $product->is_type('variable') )
    {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ){
            $price_min  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_sale_price('min') ) );
            $price_max  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_sale_price('max') ) );
        } else {
            $price_min  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_regular_price('min') ) );
            $price_max  = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_regular_price('max') ) );
        }

        if( $price_min != $price_max ){
            if( $price_min == 0 && $price_max > 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_max );
            elseif( $price_min > 0 && $price_max == 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_min );
            else
                $price = wc_format_price_range( $price_min, $price_max );
        } else {
            if( $price_min > 0 )
                $price = wc_price( $price_min);
        }
    }
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple') )
    {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $active_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );
            
        } else {
            $active_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
        }
        if ( $active_price > 0 )
            $price = wc_price($active_price);
    }
    return $price;
}

// Product Variation displayed prices
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 3);
function custom_variation_price( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    $reg_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => $variation->get_regular_price() ) );
    $sale_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => $variation->get_sale_price() ) ) ;

    if( is_user_logged_in() )
        $data['price_html'] = wc_price( $sale_price );

    else
        $data['price_html'] = wc_price( $reg_price );

    return $data;
}

// Set the correct prices in cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_item_cart_prices', 20, 1 );
function set_item_cart_prices( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price() );
        }
    }
}
```

It works but it only displays for logged customers the sale price and I need both regular and sale prices. I can see how the two different prices are determined depending on if the customer is logged in or not but I can't scale it to my needs. Could someone help me please, my PHP isn't up to scratch?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'woo_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );

function woo_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {  
    
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {      
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );   
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woo_print_login_to_see', 31 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woo_print_login_to_see', 11 );
    }
}

function woo_print_login_to_see() {
    global $product; 
    //echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Login to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
    //$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
    //$price_sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);

    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
      // echo $product->get_sale_price();
    }
    echo $product->get_regular_price();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rajeev-singh but this isn't quite the answer. I need to display the regular price for guests as well

Comment: Now I have changed my answers  like when the user is not logged-in then will shoe only regular price, few lines are commented for more hint